# How can I get a function to execute every time it receives output from another function? (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have some pseudo code below:

```
function generateNumber() {
  const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
  console.log('Original Number')
  console.log(n)
  return {
    n
  };
}

function loop() {
  const rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (4000 - 600)) + 600;
  setTimeout(() => {
    generateNumber();
    add_1();
    loop();

  }, rand);
}

function add_1() {
  const x = generateNumber() + 1;
  console.log('New Number')
  console.log(x)
}

loop()
```

What I want is for `add_1()` to execute every time `generateNumber()` outputs a number. So for now, `generateNumber()` will output a value and it immediately goes to `add_1()`, where a value of 1 is added to the incoming number, which is then sent back out. The `loop()` function is there just to get `generateNumber()` to continuously output values at different times. But in reality it could be that I want a sensor to provide data, and every time it sends a value, I want the data to go into a function (i.e. `add_1()`).

**Is my only option to have `generateNumber()` and `add_1()` in a function together? (Which is the case in the pseudo code above)**

I want it so that `add_1()` executes every time it gets input. **Preferably without needing `add_1()` to be in a function, or loop, with `generateNumber()`.**

My guess is `add_1()` has to be an async function and has to wait for some sort of promise from `generateNumber()`.

You can see in the code, that there is nothing to "trigger" `add_1()` to execute, so I believe my question is how to create this "trigger" based on output from `generateNumber()`.

Comment: look into using [Events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) if you want something to trigger a function

Comment: `generate_number()` returns an object. Why are you trying to add 1 to it?

Comment: Why doesn't `loop()` use the value returned from `generateNumber()`? `add_1()` is generating a different number from the one in `loop()`.

Comment: There are no automatic events when a function executes. Why don't you just modify `generateNumber()` to call `add_1()`?

Comment: If you can't change `generateNumber()`, you can monkey-patch it.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for the suggestions, I am not very familiar with JS, but I now realize that generateNumber() was returning an object in the original code above, I needed it to be an integer. I have been playing around with your suggestions and used `loop()` to use the value from `generateNumber()`. I will also try the monkey patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monkey-patch `generateNumber()`.

```
var oldGenerateNumber = generateNumber;
generateNumber = function() {
    const ret = oldGenerateNumber();
    add_1();
    return ret;
};
```